Como crear procedimiento almacenado que reciba 2 variables para devolver registros
tengo la siguiente tabla

y he puesto este procedimiento almacenado el cual me devuelve los registros en forma de columnas
DELIMITER !!
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE rp_resumen_ventas_fecha()
BEGIN
SET @SQL = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('ifnull(SUM(case when vendedor=''',vendedor,''' then total end),0) AS `',vendedor, '`')) INTO @sql FROM ventaslistado;
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT fecha, ', @sql, ' FROM ventaslistado GROUP BY fecha');
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END!!
DELIMITER ;

resultado del procedimiento:

Como podria modificar el procedimiento para que reciba 2 variables: fechainicio, fechafin y me devuelva solo los registros entre esas fechas.
Gracias

creo que lo he resuelto asi:
DELIMITER !!
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE ventasfecha(IN inicio DATE,IN fin DATE)
BEGIN
  SET @SQL = NULL;
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('ifnull(SUM(case when vendedor=''',vendedor,''' then total end),0) AS `',vendedor, '`')) INTO @sql FROM ventaslistado;
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT fecha, ', @sql, ' FROM ventaslistado WHERE fecha BETWEEN \'',inicio,'\' AND \'',fin,'\' GROUP BY fecha');
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END!!
DELIMITER ;

Espero a alguien le sirva

Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo tu código responde a la pregunta. Puede que tú mismo/a entiendas qué hace la consulta, pero otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar, no. Lee [answer].
